# How to remove help(?) in QWizard?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

How to remove that help(?) in the QWizard window.

Example application Img

[image]

Edit: Here is the code. This is simple application from Qt. I just want to disable that and have help button instead. I got to know how to add help buttons in each page but couldn't find solution to remove help (?) option

```
from PyQt4.Qt import *


def createIntroPage():
    page = QWizardPage()
    page.setTitle("Introduction")

    label = QLabel("This wizard will help you register your copy of "
            "Super Product Two.")
    label.setWordWrap(True)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(label)
    page.setLayout(layout)

    return page


def createRegistrationPage():
    page = QWizardPage()
    page.setTitle("Registration")
    page.setSubTitle("Please fill both fields.")

    nameLabel = QLabel("Name:")
    nameLineEdit = QLineEdit()

    emailLabel = QLabel("Email address:")
    emailLineEdit = QLineEdit()

    layout = QGridLayout()
    layout.addWidget(nameLabel, 0, 0)
    layout.addWidget(nameLineEdit, 0, 1)
    layout.addWidget(emailLabel, 1, 0)
    layout.addWidget(emailLineEdit, 1, 1)
    page.setLayout(layout)
    return page


def createConclusionPage():
    page = QWizardPage()
    page.setTitle("Conclusion")

    label = QLabel("You are now successfully registered. Have a nice day!")
    label.setWordWrap(True)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(label)
    page.setLayout(layout)
    return page


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    wizard = QWizard()
    wizard.addPage(createIntroPage())
    wizard.addPage(createRegistrationPage())
    wizard.addPage(createConclusionPage())

    wizard.setWindowTitle("Trivial Wizard")
    wizard.show()

sys.exit(wizard.exec_())
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post relevant parts of your code?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal I have added the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the context help icon using the `setWindowFlags()` method.

```
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)
```

Please post relavent code samples so we can give you a more specific answer. This is only a general idea on how to disable the button.

Feel free to ask if you need to know anything else. Hope it helps :)